# Issue with navigation in responsive tablet mode on initial page load

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, navigation, dropdown

I have a navigation in which the normal links presented on a desktop are shrunk to a button which when clicked will dropdown the navigation links.. pretty standard. Where I am having an issue is in when the page is initially loaded in the tablet size (between 767px-991px), it is shrunk off to the right. If loaded in any other media query size it works fine.

[image: This is what is happening with the navigation.]

The above is the problem... obviously. The below is what this is supposed to look like.
[image: This is what the navigation is supposed to look like.]
I've tried recreating in the inspector tools mobile area and cannot reproduce the issue there. It does happen in firefox, chrome, and safari. The website is live at http://alexleloup.com. I'm happy to post the code here if its more appropriate, however there were so many pages of code i thought posting the website would be easier. Would appreciate any feedback. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just set `width: auto;` or `width: fit-content;` in main instead of 100%.

```
@media (max-width: 991px)
#header .header-nav-main{
  width: auto;
}
```

OR

```
@media (max-width: 991px)
  #header .header-nav-main{
    width: fit-content;
}
```